# How to draw a rectangle around a TImage when it is selected

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I have a set of TImage instances layed out on a panel. The TImages represent icons (see attached screenshot). I would like to draw a red rectangle around a given TImage instance when the user selects it by clicking on it. Not sure how to proceed...

Edit: why am I not using a TToolbar? Reason 1: I don't like the default "look and feel" of the TToolbar and I want to have more control on it. Reason 2: This control is not really a TToolbar. It should rather be considered as a sort of "bookmark" element, which displays different text in the memo field depending on which "bookmark" is selected.

[image]

The accepted solution using Remy Lebeau's suggestion is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Put each on a wincontrol, e.g. a panel, which has a click event. Give padding and color to the panels.

Comment: If I were you, I'd use a custom control for this.

Comment: Better yet, use flat toolbuttons or similar.... Looks like a toolbar afterall.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz That was my first thought, but how would you make the border red?

Comment: Also, there's technically no way to "select" a `TImage` - it is a graphic control, which is deliberately designed to not get focus. Please define "selected"? Do you mean a button that currently has focus? Or a button which represents the currently viewed page?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I was referring to your second comment about using tool buttons.

Comment: @Jerry - I was suggesting using toolbars instead of images actually.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Oh I see what you mean now. Wouldn't that be transparent though, showing all red?

Comment: @Jerry - I don't see a problem with transparency. Border color would be more of a problem probably, replacing images in imagelist might be required. I was misremembering down state had an other list, that one is for actually hot states.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Oh okay, I was thinking of the speed button. I haven't used the tool button too much. Those VCL controls are quite outdated and designed for ancient versions of Windows and the UI standards back then =P The speed button shows transparent, and when inside of a colored panel, if I recall, the color would show right through. I would use a rectangle shape instead.

Comment: The toolbar with flat buttons would be best, as @Sertac suggested. An alternative is a panel with flat speedbuttons. With either of them, a visual indicator is displayed when the mouse is over them, and if you need to use them as toggles they have Down properties.

Comment: Going off of my very first comment here, I've been inspired to mimic this in a single custom control: http://pastebin.com/u5XZ4Vfy - keep in mind it's EXTREMELY raw still and in the works. I've been working on similar concepts lately, and while there are controls in later versions of Delphi which can do this, I have also been writing a library of my own custom controls which work the way I want. None of what I'm doing is in any way ready to share in GitHub yet.

Comment: @Jerry you aren't calling BeginPaint in your paint message handler.

Comment: @David I'm just barely starting this control. There are hundreds of things I'm not doing yet.

Comment: @Jerry ok, never mind

Comment: @JerryDodge, *"I've been inspired to mimic this in a single custom control"* You should override `TCustomControl.Paint` method instead of handling `WMPaint`.

Comment: @kobik Jerry made it clear to me that he didn't want help with this control because he was going to fix all the mistakes later

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest using a `TPaintBox` instead of a `TImage`.  Load your image into an appropriate `TGraphic` class (`TBitmap`, `TIcon`, `TPNGImage`, etc) and then draw it onto the `TPaintBox` in its `OnPaint` event.  That is all a `TImage` really does (it holds a `TGraphic` that is drawn onto its `Canvas` when painted).  You can then draw a red rectangle on top of the image when needed. For example:

```
procedure TMyForm.PaintBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PaintBox1.Tag := 1;
  PaintBox1.Invalidate;
  PaintBox2.Tag := 0;
  PaintBox2.Invalidate;
end;

procedure TMyForm.PaintBox2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PaintBox1.Tag := 0;
  PaintBox1.Invalidate;
  PaintBox2.Tag := 1;
  PaintBox2.Invalidate;
end;

procedure TMyForm.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(MyImage1, 0, 0);
  if PaintBox1.Tag = 1 then
  begin
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Rectangle(PaintBox1.ClientRect);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyForm.PaintBox2Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PaintBox2.Canvas.Draw(MyImage2, 0, 0);
  if PaintBox2.Tag = 1 then
  begin
    PaintBox2.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    PaintBox2.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
    PaintBox2.Canvas.Rectangle(PaintBox2.ClientRect);
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, you can derive a new class from `TImage` and override its virtual `Paint()` method to draw the rectangle after default drawing.  For example:

```
type
  TMyImage = class(TImage)
  private
    FShowRectangle: Boolean;
    procedure SetShowRectangle(Value: Boolean);
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    property ShowRectangle: Boolean read FShowRectangle write SetShowRectangle;
  end;

procedure TMyImage.SetShowRectangle(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if FShowRectangle <> Value then
  begin
    FShowRectangle := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

type
  TGraphicControlAccess = class(TGraphicControl)
  end;

procedure TMyImage.Paint;
begin
  inherited;
  if FShowRectangle then
  begin
    with TGraphicControlAccess(Self).Canvas do
    begin
      Brush.Style := bsClear;
      Pen.Color := clRed;
      Rectangle(ClientRect);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

```
procedure TMyForm.MyImage1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyImage1.ShowRectangle := true;
  MyImage2.ShowRectangle := false;
end;

procedure TMyForm.MyImage2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyImage1.ShowRectangle := false;
  MyImage2.ShowRectangle := true;
end;
```

Comment: If you use graphic other than TBitmap for TImage, trying to modify the TImage Canvas (in `TMyImage.Paint`) wont work and will raise: `Can only modify an image if it contains a bitmap.` You need to modify the `inherited Canvas` of the `TImage` ancestor i.e. `TGraphicControl.Canvas`

Comment: That wont work either.  You need inhrited of inhertited Canvas. Its a bit tricky since you need acess to private FCanvas of TImage...

Comment: @kobik you are right. And I even stated the same issue in an earlier [Embarcadero forum discussion](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=166025), so I have updated my example here again.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, nice solution type-casting TGraphicControlAccess and accessing protected Canvas property.

Answer (score 1):

I would modify the proposals. there would be no problem with the objects on the form type the following :

```
TImage = class(ExtCtrls.TImage)
  private
    FShowRectangle: Boolean;
    procedure SetShowRectangle(Value: Boolean);
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    property ShowRectangle: Boolean read FShowRectangle write SetShowRectangle;
  end;
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using a TRectangle. You can add an bitmap (bitmap, jpg, etc) via the Fill propery and set the Stroke property for the border.

You also can set the xRadius and yRadius properties for rounded borders.